# Concatenate div id with position() xsl

Tags: xslt

Hello i concatenate a function xsl position() with a div id but when i try to transform the div into a block (display block in css), that doesn't work.
This is my xsl code :

```
<!--    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />-->

        <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="final" select="concat('final', position())"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't tell us something doesn't work, tell us how it fails. Error message? Incorrect output? No output?

The expected output from `position()` depends on the context in which it appears, and you haven't shown us enough context to know what output to expect here. Is the code within an `xsl:for-each` instruction?

People sometimes expect that `position()` should output 3 if the context item is an element and the element is the third element child of its parent. That expectation is incorrect. It would only be correct if the invoking `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` happens to be processing all the child elements using `select="*"`.